# Can I list-initialize std::vector with perfect forwarding of the elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, perfect-forwarding, list-initialization

I noticed that <s>aggregate</s> *list* initalization of std::vector performs **copy initialization** when **move** is more applicable. At the same time, multiple emplace_backs do what I want.

I could only come up with this imperfect solution of writing a template function `init_emplace_vector`. It's only optimal for *non-explicit single-value* constructors, though.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::vector<T> init_emplace_vector(Args&&... args)
{
  std::vector<T> vec;
  vec.reserve(sizeof...(Args));  // by suggestion from user: eerorika
  (vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);  // C++17
  return vec;
}
```

---

## Question

**Do I really need to use emplace_back** in order to initialize std::vector as efficiently as possible?

```cpp
// an integer passed to large is actually the size of the resource
std::vector<large> v_init {
  1000,  // instance of class "large" is copied
  1001,  // copied
  1002,  // copied
};

std::vector<large> v_emplaced;
v_emplaced.emplace_back(1000);  // moved
v_emplaced.emplace_back(1001);  // moved
v_emplaced.emplace_back(1002);  // moved

std::vector<large> v_init_emplace = init_emplace_vector<large>(
  1000,   // moved
  1001,   // moved
  1002    // moved
);
```

---

## Output

Class `large` produces information about copies/moves (implementation below) and so the output of my program is:

```
- initializer
large copy
large copy
large copy
- emplace_back
large move
large move
large move
- init_emplace_vector
large move
large move
large move
```

### Large class implementation

My implementation of `large` is simply a copyable/movable type holding a large resource that warns on copy/move.

```cpp
struct large
{
  large(std::size_t size) : size(size), data(new int[size]) {}

  large(const large& rhs) : size(rhs.size), data(new int[rhs.size])
  {
    std::copy(rhs.data, rhs.data + rhs.size, data);
    std::puts("large copy");
  }

  large(large&& rhs) noexcept : size(rhs.size), data(rhs.data)
  {
    rhs.size = 0;
    rhs.data = nullptr;
    std::puts("large move");
  }

  large& operator=(large rhs) noexcept
  {
    std::swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
  }

  ~large() { delete[] data; }

  int* data;
  std::size_t size;
};
```

#### Edit

By using reserve, there is no copy or move. Only `large::large(std::size_t)` constructor is invoked. True emplace.

Comment: It's not aggregate-initialization, you are calling the constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: std::vector's constructors are a confusing mess IMHO, and if I were you I'd really avoid getting into it if I don't absolutely have to. Plus, if you know you vectors' contents in advance (which seems like it might be the case) - consider an `std::array`.

Comment: An `operator=` which destroys the source is quite unusual and might cause unexpected problems.

Comment: `init_emplace_vector` could be improved with `vec.reserve(sizeof...(Args))`

Comment: @alain `operator=` does not destroy the source. It's the copy-swap idiom.

Comment: I swear I saw a `large& operator=(large& rhs)` here, however now it's not in the edit history. Yes, `large& operator=(large rhs)` is fine, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can I aggregate-initialize std::vector ...

No. `std::vector` is not an aggregate, so it cannot be aggregate-initialised.

You may mean list-initialisation instead, in which case:

> Can I *[list-initialise]* std::vector with perfect forwarding of the elements?

No. List-initialisation uses the `std::initializer_list` constructor and `std::initializer_list` copies its arguments.

Your `init_emplace_vector` appears to be a decent solution, although it can be improved by reserving the memory before emplacing the elements.