# Program uses Copy Constructor instead of Move Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++17, copy-constructor

I am trying to understand the concept of copy and move constructors in C++. And so trying out different examples. One such example whose output i am unable to understand is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct NAME 
{
    NAME()
    {
        std::cout<<"default"<<std::endl;
    }
    NAME(const NAME& )
    {
        std::cout<<"const copy"<<std::endl;
    }
    NAME(NAME& )
    {
        std::cout<<"nonconst copy"<<std::endl;
    }
    NAME(NAME &&)
    {
        std::cout<<"move"<<std::endl;
    }
};
void foo(std::pair<std::string, NAME> ) 
{
    
}
void foo2(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, NAME>> )
{
}
int main()
{
    foo(std::make_pair("an", NAME())); //prints default --> move --> move
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    
    foo({"an", NAME()});               //prints default --> move
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    
    foo2({{"an", NAME()}});            //prints default --> move --> const copy
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Case 1**: For `foo(std::make_pair("an", NAME()));`

Output

```
default
move
move
```

This is what i think is happening.

Step 1. A temporary of type NAME() is craeted because we've passed it to `std::make_pair` using the `NAME()`'s default constructor.

Step 2. One of the `std::make_pair`'s constructor is used which forwards(moves) the the temporary that was created in the 1st step. So `NAME()`'s move constructor.

Step 3. Finally, since the argument to `foo` is passed by value, so the `std::pair` that was created in step 2 is "moved"(not "copied"?) which in turn "moves" the `NAME` temporary one last time.

**Case 2**: For `foo({"an", NAME()});`

Output

```
default
move
```

Step 1. A temporary `NAME` is created.

Step 2. This time since we do not have `std::make_pair`, `std::pair`'s initializer list constructor(if any) is used to "move" the temporary created in step 1.

**Case 3**: For `foo2({{"an", NAME()}});`

Output

```
default
move
const copy
```

I have no idea **why copy constructor is used** instead of move constructor and also **why the `const` version is used instead of nonconst version** of copy constructor.

Are my explanation correct. Please *correct me* **where** i am wrong in any of my explanation steps in detail.

Comment: A non-const copy constructor shouldn’t be a thing.

Comment: @sweenish Believe it or not, non-const copy constructor is a C++ thing. Any constructor for a class T that has one mandatory argument of type `T &` or `T const &` (it may also have further, defaulted arguments) is a copy constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why copy constructor is called in std::vector's initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420829/why-copy-constructor-is-called-in-stdvectors-initializer-list)

Comment: For the related question of how to get around this: [Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/) and [Can I list-initialize std::vector with perfect forwarding of the elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655413/)

Comment: @JaMiT But if initilalizer_list uses copy constructor then why in Case 2's point 2 move constructor is used? That is, in my explanation of Case 2 look at point 2. There also `std::pair`'s initializer_list constructor is used then there also the copy constructor should be used.

Comment: Also, from the past hour or so: [How to avoid copying when creating a vector argument from an initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954424/)

Comment: How do you imagine case 2 constructs a *vector*? Where is the vector in case 2?

Comment: @JaMiT There is no vector in Case 2. But there `std::pair`'s intializer_list constructor is used. And according to the answer given by yurikilochek, elements of `std::inializer_list` are `const` and so cannot be moved. This means the temporary `NAME()` is also `const`. So in case 2 the const copy constructor should be used instead of move constructor.

Comment: I am not yuri kilochek; requests for clarification of an answer should be directed to the answer's author. I have no additional insight to offer. I found other questions (with answers) related to initializing vectors. You asked about initializing a vector. QED. If you want to ask about initializing a pair, you can ask a new question after checking to see if it's already been asked and answered.

Comment: @AanchalSharma `std::pair` has nothing to do with `std::initializer_list`. An expression in curly braces does not `std::initializer_list` is involved.

Comment: I wasn't speaking to whether you can write one or not. *Shouldn't* implies poor practices in this case. C++ will always let you shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

Elements of `std::initializer_list`, are `const` and cannot be moved from.

Comment: does this mean my explanation for other two calls to `foo` are correct?

Comment: @AanchalSharma basically yes.

Answer (score 0):

> **Case 1:** For `foo(std::make_pair("an", NAME()));`
>
> Output
>
> ```
> default
> move
> move
> ```

The crucial issue here is to understand what is the type of the above `make_pair` invocation. It is **not** a `std::pair<std::string, NAME>` as I think you believe, but a `std::pair<const char *, NAME>` !

You can confirm this by checking that this prints `1`.

```
std::cout << std::is_same_v< decltype(std::make_pair("an", NAME()))
                           , std::pair<const char *, NAME>> << "\n";
```

So, we observe that:

1. `NAME` is constructed using the default constructor. (output: `default`)
2. `make_pair` moves that to return its pair (output: `move`)
3. We can not pass that pair to `foo`, which instead expects `std::pair<std::string, NAME>`. An implicit `pair` conversion constructor is called, which creates the `string` and moves the `NAME` once again. (output: `move`)

This is why we observe two moves instead of just one.

> **Case 2:** For `foo({"an", NAME()});`
>
> Output
>
> ```
> default
> move
> ```

Here we don't call a function to make the pair, so `"an"` is used to initialize the needed pair directly, which has the right `std::pair<std::string, NAME>`. We no longer create a pair with the "wrong" type, hence one fewer move.

On **case 3**: I could not understand why the move constructor is called in case 3. I thought that in order to allow `vector` to move the `NAME`, it would have sufficed to mark the move constructor as `noexcept`, but even in that case the copy is performed. I have no idea right now.

It looks like the move constructor of `std::pair` is not (conditionally) `noexcept` as one would expect. That might be the underlying cause.

Comment: Can you tell me which among [these](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) is used? Or is it aggregate initialization.

Comment: @AanchalSharma I wish I knew for sure. My guess is that in case 2 it's copy-list-initialization, calling (3). In case 1, we instead call (5) as an implicit.